# why does my code output an improper value?

Tags: c, if-statement, printf, ascii

this is my code in C:-

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a=300, b, c;
    if(a>=400)
        b=300;
    c=200;
    printf("%c %d\n", b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

it returns a value 57 200.
which doesn't even represent ascii values. what is happening

Comment: `b` is uninitialized... Why would it represent `ASCII` value?

Comment: Indeed. You won't say that `printf("%c", 'A')` is UB, right?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how `printf("%c", x);` could print `57` for any value of `x`.

Comment: @FredLarson Nasal demons? :) I would rather suspect a false report though.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: Perhaps. Interesting demons. Yeah, I think false report is more likely.

Comment: The variable `b` will not be initialized for the condition `a < 400`.

Answer (score 4):

You don't initialize `b`. This leads to your code having [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

Answer (score 0):

it was a question in one of the beginner books and had to predict the output.
yes it doesn't initialize b so it outputs garbage value which in the case of me testing the code showed 57(being a garbage value)